# Why isn't this PDO Exception getting caught?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have an INSERT wrapped in a try/catch, but a missing table is not getting caught and PHP is erroring out at '$dbh->prepare'.
I've set the 'PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE' and the value echoed to the browser just before the '$dbh->prepare' is 2.

If the table exists, the INSERT works as I expected.  I only discovered there was an issue while testing when I purposely dropped the table and ran the code.

What have I overlooked?

Thanks in advance

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: submit_info' in C:\etc\httpd\htdocs\sqlite_data\gather.php:309

```
if($our->db['save']) {
    try {
        echo $dbh->getAttribute(constant('PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'));
        $sth = $dbh->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO submit_info( post_time, post_completed, post_size , script_name, user_agent  )" .
            " VALUES ( datetime(:request_time, 'unixepoch'), datetime(:current_time, 'unixepoch'), :content_length, :script_filename, :user_agent );"
            );
        $sth->bindValue(':request_time', (@$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] + 0), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindValue(':current_time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindValue(':content_length', (@$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] + 0), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindValue(':script_filename', @$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':user_agent', (@$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . ''), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        $our->db['submit_id'] = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
        echo "There was an error!"; # try writing something to the browser temporarily
        errors("Error writing page load information to database: " . $e->getMessage());
        $our->db['save'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelt `PDOException`;  you have `PDOExeption` (note the missing `c`).

Comment: That was indeed the problem.  This is the first PDO project I've worked on.  I spent 2 hours reviewing the documentation and logic because of that missing letter.  Komodo usually flags misspellings or I get a run-time error in the log pointing me in the right direction.
Thank you for your help!